# How would all the adults vanish?

Tags: science-based, magic

How would it be plausible for in a world without magic that all the people older than 15 disappear for a length of time of 6 years. I have never been a science freak or a mathematician so I’m not sure what would happen to make everyone disappear. What I want to happen that in the middle of a day all the adults disappeared only leaving their clothes behind. But I don’t want the parents to age and also when they return after the 6 years they're NOT naked. And I also don’t want aliens or a crazy daisies or maybe a horrible disease.

Answer (score 3):

[science-based](/questions/tagged/science-based)? Forget it! What you ask for requires pure [magic](/questions/tagged/magic).

- We have no reliable way to tell 15-year-olds from 14-year-olds or 16-year-olds.
- There is no way as we understand it to "put people on ice" for six years without change. Science fiction talks about cryogenic suspension, but we are not up to reviving [corpsicles](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HumanPopsicle) yet.
- Accelerating them to close to lightspeed would theoretically do the job as far as aging is concerned, but the required energy is *totally* off the scale.
- They are supposed to *leave* their clothes behind and then come back fully clothed? Where would the spare set of clothing come from?

This sounds like high-end space opera technology, perhaps Star Trek or Iain Banks' [Culture](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheCulture) setting. Powerful computers, replicator technologies, matter transmission. Even so they'd need some preparation time to pull it off, and for a present-day world they'd be aliens.

Comment: Peter F. Hamilton's Ozzie could steal them away.

Comment: @Ash, at least for the first couple of series he'd lack both the computing power and the wormhole hardware to pull this off quickly. The Rajel, maybe.

Comment: Yeah unless the A.I. dude(s) got in on it, thanks for reminding me to read the other books in that universe I've only read _Pandora's Star_ and _Judas Unchained_.

Answer (score 2):

Nanomachines in the water supply that get passed to the offspring, and get triggered when they detect the presence of air in the lungs (i.e. the infant being born), and then begin a countdown to sending a signal to teleporters that send them... wherever it is they go.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two viable answers I can see to this question, both require ubiquitous surveillance for targeting purposes they are [The Fey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy) who are notorious for this sort of stunt and [ASBs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_space_bats) it would be far from the weirdest thing *they've* ever been accused of.